# How to retrieve data from Access Database, when user are login to the program?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

to all my senior. I'm doing an assignment about Music Sales System.

When the system begin will start a form "Login.vb", it allow the user to login with Staff ID and Password. After that, if login successful it will show the name of the staff in a textbox.

Could any senior help me or teach me how to retrieve the name when the staff login to the system?

Furthermore, I also like to retrieve picture from Access Database, hope can get some help from here.

I'm using Jet.Oledb.4.0.

Thank You.

Below is my Login.vb code

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

```
    Dim Connection As New Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Music_Sales_Database.mdb;")
    Dim Command As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT [Staff_ID] FROM [Staff] WHERE [Staff_IDField] = Staff_ID AND [PasswordField] = Password", Connection)

    Dim StaffIDParam As New Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("Staff_ID", Me.txtStaff_ID.Text)
    Dim PasswordParam As New Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("Password", Me.txtPassword.Text)

    Command.Parameters.Add(StaffIDParam)
    Command.Parameters.Add(PasswordParam)

    Command.Connection.Open()

    Dim Reader As Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()

    If txtStaff_ID.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Staff ID and Password cannot be empty, please try again.", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
    ElseIf txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Staff ID and Password cannot be empty, please try again.", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
    ElseIf Reader.HasRows Then
        MessageBox.Show("You are authenticated.", "Login Successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
        MyPlayer.SoundLocation = path & LogOnSound
        MyPlayer.Play()
        txtPassword.Text = ""
        Me.Hide()
        Main_System.Show()

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Staff ID or Password, please try again.", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        txtPassword.Text = ""
        txtPassword.Focus()
    End If

    Command.Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

********BELOW is the program that Im coding, but still coding.......coz Im still new in VB.....hope can get some help

```
Dim Connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim Command As OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim Reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
Dim DBPath As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Music_Sales_Database.mdb;"
Dim Image() As Byte

Private Sub RetrieveStaffInformation()
Connection.ConnectionString = DBPath
Connection.Open()

Command = Connection.CreateCommand
Command.CommandText = "SELECT        Staff.* FROM            Staff"

Reader = Command.ExecuteReader

Image = CType(Reader(0), Byte())
Dim MS As New System.IO.MemoryStream(Image)
Dim bmImage As New Bitmap(MS)

picStaff.Image = bmImage
picStaff.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: show us the relevant parts of your code please..

Comment: @Codemunkeee I posted the code...thx

Comment: the login.vb is 100% work, but i dunno how to code for the retrieving data from access when the user login successful

Comment: i would like to get the text from txtStaff_ID and pass to another form  textbox and display it, after that will use the text to retrieve data from access database

Answer (score 0):

I give you code for sql.change it to access

```
    Dim com As SqlCommand
    com = New SqlCommand("select uname,pwd from logg where uname='" & TextBox1.Text & "' and pwd='" & TextBox2.Text & "'", conn)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(com)
    Dim ds As New Data.DataSet
    da.Fill(ds)
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox("Successfully logged in")
        Label1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("uname")
    End If
```